# Fetch driver session id in karate for Video recording

Tags: selenium, karate, selenium-grid

I currently need to implement the [video recording](https://github.com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node) feature in karate. The recording tool requires the session id to download the recorded video. Is there a function in karate to get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something we had not considered, but has just been added to the code: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/86035744e8f2f3fe1e3de666296aab2d6dc2e8a4

You can build from source and help us validate to enable a faster release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide